# Como inserir uma quebra de linha em um appendChild, é possível?

Tags: javascript, quebras-de-linha

Preciso de uma quebra de linha depois de um appendChild ou seria depois do input? sou iniciante em JS e to meio perdido de como fazer essa quebra de linha.

```
var inp1 = document.createElement('input')
            var inp1 = document.createElement('input')



            var text1 = document.createTextNode('Digite o primeiro numero: ')
            var text2 = document.createTextNode('Digite o segundo numero: ')



            div.appendChild(text1)
            div.appendChild(inp1) //quebra de linha no final do input
            div.appendChild(text2)

            var container = document.querySelector('#div')
            container.appendChild(div)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá amigo, o começo pode parecer um pouco confuso, mas tomando cuidado e prestando atenção no que você está desenvolvendo tudo pode funcionar.

Primeiro, o código está repetindo a criação do *input* na primeira e segunda linha:

```
var inp1 = document.createElement('input')
var inp1 = document.createElement('input')
```

Segundo, você tem o elemento *div* que não foi criado no código que compartilhou:

```
            div.appendChild(text1)
            div.appendChild(inp1) //quebra de linha no final do input
            div.appendChild(text2)
```

No mais preste atenção nos nomes das variaveis, tente sempre deixar o mais legível possível. Segue o código de como poderia ser:

```
  var inputFirstNumber = document.createElement('input')

  var labelFirstNumber = document.createTextNode('Digite o primeiro numero: ')
  var labelSecondNumber = document.createTextNode('Digite o segundo numero: ')

  var div1 = document.createElement('div')
  var div2 = document.createElement('div')
  var div3 = document.createElement('div')

  div1.appendChild(labelFirstNumber)
  div2.appendChild(inputFirstNumber)
  div3.appendChild(labelSecondNumber)

  var container = document.querySelector('#container')
  container.appendChild(div1)
  container.appendChild(div2)
  container.appendChild(div3)
```

Link para Codepen:  https://codepen.io/kleberoliveira/pen/YzXoWzj

Boa sorte!

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, muito bom ter concelhos assim no inicio! vou seguir seus concelhos! Criei os 3 elementos div e deu certinho, muito obrigado!

Comment: @JanioAlbuquerque Repare que a solução do seu problema nem tem relação com JS, é uma questão de HTML. CSS poderia ser usado também se necessário.